# Does anyone know how to use Faunadb in unity? or their c# driver in unity?

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, faunadb

I am curious if there is a possibility that we can use Faunadb drivers in unity

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/cicanci/fauna-unity
All credits to Bruno Cicanci.